# Не удается запустить jetty

Tags: java, веб-программирование, веб-сервер, jetty

Сейчас изучаю web-разработку на java, в уроках на Stepik используется jetty
(https://stepik.org/course/146/syllabus)
В конце первой части нужно скачать примеры из репа
(https://github.com/vitaly-chibrikov/stepic_java_webserver ) 
и запустить первый пример, но при запуске возникает такая проблема

```html
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -javaagent:/opt/intellij-idea-community/lib/idea_rt.jar=36657:/opt/intellij-idea-community/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/icedtea-sound.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/geo/Documents/JavaProject/stepic_java_webserver/L1.1 Simple web server/target/classes:/home/geo/.m2/repository/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.20/freemarker-2.3.20.jar:/home/geo/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.3.0.M0/jetty-server-9.3.0.M0.jar:/home/geo/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/geo/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.3.0.M0/jetty-http-9.3.0.M0.jar:/home/geo/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.3.0.M0/jetty-util-9.3.0.M0.jar:/home/geo/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.3.0.M0/jetty-io-9.3.0.M0.jar:/home/geo/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.3.0.M0/jetty-webapp-9.3.0.M0.jar:/home/geo/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/9.3.0.M0/jetty-xml-9.3.0.M0.jar:/home/geo/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.3.0.M0/jetty-servlet-9.3.0.M0.jar:/home/geo/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.3.0.M0/jetty-security-9.3.0.M0.jar" main.Main
2017-11-29 00:51:24.912:INFO::main: Logging initialized @836ms
2017-11-29 00:51:25.004:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.0.M0
2017-11-29 00:51:25.177:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3d04a311{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-11-29 00:51:25.187:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED ServerConnector@7a46a697{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:328)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:244)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:367)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
 at main.Main.main(Main.java:25)
2017-11-29 00:51:25.188:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@5f205aa: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:328)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:244)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:367)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
 at main.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:328)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:244)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:367)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
 at main.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

ну и программа не запускается

Comment: У вас уже кто-то слушает на этом порту.

Comment: вот что выдает по поводу прослушки
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)

как  можно отключить прослушку по этому порту

Comment: Гляньте, кто именно занимает порт. `sudo netstat -peanut | grep ":8080 "` что выдаёт?

Comment: tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      121        24566       1589/java

Comment: Ну, какое-то джава приложение висит в памяти и занимает порт. Вероятно, это после прошлого запуска. Убейте приложение это и попробуйте запустить после этого.

Comment: а как его убить?( я перезагружал комп перед запуском )

Comment: `sudo kill  1589` или через утилиту какую-нибудь. Я обычно htop использую. Установите её себе, очень полезная штука.

Comment: Спасибо заработало)

Comment: Оформил как ответ, чтоб другим могло помочь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Надо найти, кто использует порт. На Linux командой: `sudo netstat -peanut | grep ":8080 "`.
2. Убить приложение, которое порт использует. Стандартными средствами так: `sudo kill 1589`, где `1589` - это PID процесса.